# Oracle - Aggregate from two tables

Tags: oracle, sum, aggregate

I have two tables

```
ITEMLOC:
ITEM  LOC  STOCK

ORDERS:
ORDNO  ITEM  LOC  QTY
```

I want to see the following results:

```
ITEM  LOC  SUMofOrderQty  SUMofStock
```

How do I get aggregates from both the tables to compare the Stock and OrderedQty on Item and Location

Comment: Apparently, you have two tables that both have multiple records of information for each item and location.  You're going to have to SUM your stock from ITEMLOC first, in a CTE or a subquery, and then join it on ITEM and LOC to ORDERS, and SUM again there on QTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT l.item,
       l.loc,
       l.sum_of_stock,
       o.sum_of_qty
FROM   (
         SELECT   item, loc, SUM( stock ) AS sum_of_stock
         FROM     item_loc
         GROUP BY item, loc
       ) l
       INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT   item, loc, SUM( qty ) AS sum_of_qty
         FROM     orders
         GROUP BY item, loc
       ) o
       ON ( l.item = o.item AND l.loc = o.loc )
WHERE  l.sum_of_stock >= o.sum_of_qty
```

Comment: The query works great. 
If i need to filer on the condition to bring only the rows where
sum_of_stock > sum_of_qty - where do I place this condition?

Comment: @ImranHemani - Updated - you put the `WHERE` clause after the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.ITEM, a.LOC, a.SUMofOrderQty, SUMofStock from
(Select ITEM  LOC , Sum ( QTY)
FROM ORDERS
ITEM, LOC 
) a,

(Select ITEM, LOC  , Sum (STOCK) 
FROM ITEMLOC
group by ITEM, LOC ,
) b
Where a.ITEM=b.ITEM
AND b.LOC= a.LOC
```

sorry for typo

Answer (score 0):

A other way

```
Select ITEM, LOC, SUM(q),SUM(s)
FROM (
Select ITEM , LOC , 0 q ,STOCK s
FROM ITEMLOC
Union
SELECT ITEM ,LOC, QTI q ,0 s
FROM ORDERS)
group by ITEM ,LOC
```

ITEM  LOC must be primary key
If not :

```
Select ITEM, LOC, SUM(q),SUM(s)
FROM (
Select ITEM , LOC , 0 q ,sum(STOCK) s
FROM ITEMLOC
group by ITEM ,LOC
Union
SELECT ITEM ,LOC, sum(QTI) q ,0 s
FROM ORDERS
group by ITEM ,LOC)
group by ITEM ,LOC
```